# Can I run a 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS installed in a 64 bit architecture?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, virtualization

I've got a strange and complicated situation.
As a computer science student I could get a free licence of Windows 8 for 2 years but only 32 bit. So I installed it on my laptop which is a 64 bit architecture (Intel i5). Now I would need to run a 64 bit software, in particular php-5.4.8 which is the only version compiled with VC10 but it's only 64 bit. Is it possible for me to run in in any way? My cpu is 64 bit and supports virtualization and everything...maybe can I use virtualboc or vmware? And if yes, how? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried installing the software ? Because the best answer would be to practically see....

As for 64 - 32 i dont have much experience of all those stuffs in depth but in general OS stands for Operating System so 64 bit laptop architecture means a 64 storey building while 32 floors are operating (OS) so if u run 64 bit software i think it wont run since those floors are not understandable or not recognized perhapsssssss . ( dats my general analogy )

Anyways if you want to learn PHP then you can install other OS like window 7 etc... I personally work on Ubuntu...

thx